# How do i get else to restart in python

Tags: python

```
while True:
    print ('What is your name')
    name = input()
    if name == 'Joe':
        continue
    else:
        break
    print ('What is the password')
    password = input()
    if password == '123':
        break
print ('Permission Granted')
```

Whenever i type something other than Joe it brings me to the last line.I am new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"Whenever i type something other than Joe it brings me to the last line."* - that's precisely what you've asked it to do!

Comment: What do you mean by *"else to restart"*.

Comment: Check out this documentation about the `break` statement in a `while` loop. https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: While reading about break check out [continue](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly it's just that your code logic is wrong. Try:

```
while True:
    print ('What is your name')
    name = input()
    if name != 'Joe':
        continue
    print ('What is the password')
    password = input()
    if password == '123':
        break
print ('Permission Granted')
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to keep asking for a name until 'Joe' is entered. Once you get the name you want, check for the password. In this case, try:

```
while True:
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    if name != 'Joe':
        continue
    password = input('What is the password? ')
    if password == '123':
        print('Permission granted')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is helps?

```
   while True:
        print ('What is your name')
        name = input()
        if name != 'Joe': 
            continue  # if the name is not equal to 'Joe', go to the beginning of the loop     
        print ('What is the password')
        password = input()
        if password == '123':
            print ('Permission Granted')  # print this if the password is correct
            break  # if the password equals '123', exit the while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change "input()" to "raw_input()". But the while loop will keep asking "what is your name" if you keep enter "Joe"

I think this is something you are looking for.

```
while True:
        print ('What is your name')
        name = raw_input()
        if name == 'Joe':
                print ("What is the password")
                password = raw_input()
                if password == '123':
                        print ('Permission Granted')
                        break
                else:
                        continue
        else:
                continue
```

Comment: I'm guessing he's using Python3, in which case `input()` is fine.

Comment: Those `else: continue` blocks are redundant. BTW, we usually indent by 4 spaces on SO Python.